# Shopify's Ajax Cart Update Method isn't working as it should

Tags: jquery, shopify

What the problem is that I have a script running which called buy 3 get 1 free. the script works fine but whenever I try to reduce or increase the quantity of the product using "+" or "-" buttons. The ajax call is executed and it returns an odd quantity assigning the below same free product quantity to the main product quantity. Same goes for both buttons. Everything works fine until the free product is not added below by the script. The problem may also be occurring because of the same product_id being assigned to the free product too.

I've tried even deleting free product id and assigning it empty via scripts but it doesn't affect or helps. I made custom ajax requests to the change.js file the new quantity is being passed fine but the response from the server comes with the added quantity(the wrong quantity).

```js
$('.my_minus_btn').click(function() {
        var newQuantity = Number($(this).parent().find('.cart__qty-input').val())-1;
       var productid = $(this).parent().find('.cart__qty-input').data('id');
        CartJS.updateItemById(productid, newQuantity);
    
              var data = {
          quantity: newQuantity,
          id: productid
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/cart/change.js',
          data: data,
          success: function(d){console.log(d)},
          dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

What I want is that simple add or reduce quantity functions to work fine and return correct quantity.

Comment: Hi Mirza, welcome to SO :)  It would be rather difficult for someone to help without any code snippets or debugging information.  Try and narrow the question down to something more specific.

Comment: Sir, actually it's the default ajax cart code of Shopify so I haven't written it by myself. 
What I can provide is my custom ajax call which I wrote in trying to fix my problem.